# What is usage of parameter tag used in TabHost.newTabSpec

Tags: android

May I know, for the following code.

```
// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("The Artists",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
              .setContent(intent);
```

What is the purpose of having "artists" tag as the parameter of `newTagSpec`? Should I use an internationalize string like

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.artists)).setIndicator(getString(R.string.the_artists),
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
              .setContent(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did that for all my tabs but you do it like so:

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("groups").setIndicator(getString(R.string.tab_groups), res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_groups)).setContent(intent);
```

The "groups" is how it figures out R.drawable.ic_tab_NameInNewTabSpec.

Comment: But does that explain the purpose of "groups" tag? What is ic_tab_NameInNewTabSpec by the way?

Comment: It's the name you used in newTabSpec() ... That's what the "groups" tag does.  It tells the compiler to use ic_tab_groups.

Comment: Any documentation that says that's what it does?

Answer (score 5):

The tag parameter is the ID for the tab used by TabHost. The tag might be useful when overriding TabHost methods, e.g.

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nav_bar);

...

tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onTabChanged(String tabID){
       t.setText(tabID);
   }
});
```

In this example t is an TextView representing an "navigation bar" and **tabID** is the tag of the tab that the user switched to. The purpose of this simple overriden method is to change the text inside the navigation bar to the name/tag of the tab.